# Configuração do Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Instalei o Visual Studio para usar o Sfml, configurei e funcionou corretamente, mas quando crio outro projeto e fecho o anterior tenho que configurar tudo de novo para usar, as libs, includes, etc.

Como configurar de uma maneira geral, para todos os novos projetos e não um projeto em si.

Comment: Não faz sentido votar negativamente nesta questão. Alguém deveria deixar instruções sobre como criar um template de projeto ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Se eu lembrar, amanhã eu ofereço uma recompensa aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderá criar um [Modelo de Projeto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)

A partir do seu projeto, o que será o modelo para os demais, efetue os seguintes passos:

- No menu File, clique em Export Template. O assistente Export Template abre;
- Clique em Project Template;
- Se você tiver mais de um projeto na solução atual, selecione os projetos que você deseja exportar para um modelo;
- Clique em Next;
- Digite um nome para o modelo e a descrição;
- Selecione um ícone e uma imagem de visualização para o seu modelo, se desejar;
- Clique em Concluir. Seu projeto será exportado para um arquivo .zip e colocado na pasta de saída especificada, e se selecionado, será importado para o Visual Studio.

**Ao criar um novo projeto, esse seu modelo estará disponível para escolha, e com isso, todas as configurações, telas e códigos farão parte deste novo projeto.**

**Importante**
*Realize um primeira compilação para resolver todas as referências. Num primeiro momento, elas serão marcadas com um exclamação.*